# Is it secure to use a service via public wifi if logged in previously?

Tags: wireless-networking, security

For example, is it secure to use and interchange data in a gmail(facebook,instagram or whatever web-app) on a public wifi, if I have logged in previously?

So if I am not giving away my `user + password` combination and authorizing via token/cookies generated previously, am I save from data misuse (assuming https is used)? Or is still a dumb idea to read messages on public wifi?

Comment: There's a lot of good write-ups from tech magazines and tech sites available via a search engine that detail the way one should be connecting to public wifi (best policy is not to), such as configuring the firewall on the PC to block all inbound connections, except for two rules in front of this to allow for the initial DHCP connection, and a VPN should be utilized for _all_ traffic.  Browsing without a VPN allows for web traffic to be seen by anyone sniffing traffic, and any HTTP traffic will be plainly visible.  **If connecting to public WiFi, use a VPN.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is never secure to use anything over public wifi security wise.

Even though you are not giving your username+password, your token/cookies can be caught and an attacker can use this information to login to your services and change your password, locking you out of your account.

In addition, not every web app is programmed securely and may have easy to crack hashes in your cookies that they can crack in order to get your password.

Keep in mind, if a hacker uses public wifi to hack you, they will do anything they can do to get to your data. There are many methods and some may prevent them from getting your details, where others will work.

To avoid this, Either use VPN + open network, or don't connect to an open (public) wifi connection in the first place.

Also, keep in mind that aside of them logging in or not, they can see your traffic. Opening a list of your emails in gmail will give them those emails too.

Comment: But connecting to `vpn` requires authentication at the very least, so while after I authorized my messages are tunneled and can't be read, credentials to vpn are revealed, right? So I am still loosing some information

Comment: The tunnel encrypts the data, but yes they could get your VPN login details. All they can do is to setup a new VPN connection and try that password on other services. It is still very secure regardless. They cannot hack your existing tunnel with those login information though.

Comment: @anasmi all they can do is know that you have a VPN connection. The connection setup would be via a [public key exchange mechanism](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/ssl-tls-encryption-ssltls-certificates/) which, while it could be monitored, is effectively secure over non-secure links and not a long enough exchange to infer anything about or break security of the data being transferred. The data is (hopefully) a stronger symmetric connection key which secures the VPN tunnel itself. Done right a VPN is, as long as you trust your VPN provider, as secure as any other trusted network.

Comment: Hopefully your VPN software would use a "known good" certificate for the TLS/SSL certificate that is pre-downloaded over a trusted connection, but if they download it at the start of the connection then your open network could effectively MITM you and hand you a different certificate, thus exposing your key and connection. No well written VPN software would let this happen and can prevent it by preferring to store keys in the program installer. Your VPN password should not be exposed if this is done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is never secure and in urban areas where other people are around, I use my own Internet (iPhone or HUAWEI USB stick).  This prevents people from hacking into my system (has not happened in my case).

If away from many people (my cottage for example), I use the open Internet because people are most unlikely to tromp through the woods to hack my system.

So mostly (90% of the time), make sure you are secure. Occasionally you can get away from open Internet